# How can I make an HTML e-book similar to this one?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an HTML page layout similar to this one https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/b/barrie/jm/peter/index.html
 but I cannot figure out how to get the square to work as something as just in the background and stay in one place so I can put images, or text, or what ever my heart desires on top of it. I have made an image to use as the cover photo and want the shape in behind it so I can just scroll down and see my buttons for the about page and contents etc.

```css
div {
  margin-right: 300px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.square {
  width: 523px;
  height: 600px;
  Background-color: #3C3F52;
  margin-right: 300px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="peter%20pan%20cover.jpg" alt="Cover">

  <div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: The best way is by getting started. Learn html and CSS. *Note to others*: Before you start downvoting, please help point to the right direction and we can close this question.

Comment: Thanks, I know the basics of it and have completed most of the other aspects of the book, I just needed some help with trying to make it look prettier and more realistic. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something along these lines. This example can be fine-tuned. I use nested block level `div` elements and style them with `border`, `box-shadow`, etc. to give the impression of a book cover.

```css
html {
  background: #ccc;
}

.ebook {
  background: white;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  min-height: 800px;
  padding:48px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #888888;
}

.ebook p {
  font-size:40pt;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.ebook img {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display:inline-block;
}

.inner-frame {
  border:1px solid black;
  min-height:calc(800px - 96px);
}
```

```html
<div class="ebook">
<div class="inner-frame">  
  <p>My title </p>
  <img src="peter%20pan%20cover.jpg" alt="Placeholder Image">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked great thanks! I was struggling with making the box stay under everything.

Comment: That’s great! Please accept the answer if you think it’s correct. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
.square {
border: 2px solid #00609c;
height: 47em;
position: relative;
}
```